# React.js Redux actions and reducers do not get initated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am having an issue with my React-Redux app. I have created Redux action & reducer and connected them to my React component. However, it seems like it never gets to my Redux action & reducer.

I put "debugger" in my action and reducer but those debuggers never get initiated.

Could you please help me fix this issue?

Am I missing something here?

Here the current codes in the following files:

Here is the code for my app.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

import App from './components/index';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, ReduxPromise)(createStore);

render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, 
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Here is my code for index.js:

As you can see below, I put a debugger in the "componentDidMount()", and when In run it, it gets to that point.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as AllNewsApiActions from '../actions/newsApiActions';

import '../../css/style.css';

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
   this.props.getNewsApi();
   debugger;
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello from react</p>
        <p>Sample Testing</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    newNews: state.newNews
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  ...AllNewsApiActions
})(App);
```

Here is my action:

```js
import * as types from './newsTypes';

const API_KEY = "6c78608600354f199f3f13ddb0d1e71a";

export const getNewsApi = () => {
  debugger;
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'API_REQUEST',
      options: {
        method: 'GET',
        endpoint: `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=${API_KEY}`,
        actionTypes: {
          success: types.GET_NEWS_API_SUCCESS,
          error: types.GET_NEWS_API_ERROR
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my reducer:

```js
import * as types from '../actions/newsTypes';

const initialState = {
  newNews: []
};

const getNewsAPIReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.GET_NEWS_API_SUCCESS:
      debugger;
      return { ...state, newNews: action.data };
      
    case types.GET_NEWS_API_ERROR:
     debugger;
      return { ...state, error: action.data };

    default: {
      return state;
    };
  };
};

export default getNewsAPIReducer;
```

Here is the index.js file in the reducer folder:

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import NewsApiReducer from './newsApiReducer.js';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  newNews: NewsApiReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Are you using `creat-react-app`?

Comment: where  are you handling API_REQUEST in reducer and where is your action GET_NEWS_API_SUCCESS, GET_NEWS_API_ERROR

Comment: As all reducers get hit during dispatch I would put a console log just before the switch in the reducer and check what the passed action is. Just to check what youre working with.